# I am making a text based adventure game, and the action commands are not working

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

*emphasized text*Here is the code so far:

```
# This displays the game's basic instructions.
def show_instructions():
    print("The Haunted Manor")
    print("Collect Pawpaw's Lucky Charms and Break the Ancient Curse")
    print("Avoid the cursed items haunting the Manor")
    print("Move Commands: 'go north', 'go south', 'go east', 'go west'")
    print("Get Items: get 'item name'")
    print("Type 'exit' if you'd like to quit\n")

# This defines the player's status, and displays it.
def player_status():
    print(current_room['text'])
    print()
    print("You are in: {}".format(current_room['name']))
    print("Items in your possession: {}".format(current_items))
    print("You see {}".format(current_room['item']))

# The following is a dictionary of rooms, their connections, items in them, and other information
rooms = {
    'Foyer': {
        'name': 'Foyer',
        'west': 'Dining Room',
        'south': 'Great Hall',
        'east': 'Billiards Room',
        'item': 'nothing',
        'text': 'Welcome to the Foyer'
    },
    # Start Room
    'Dining Room': {
        'name': 'Dining Room',
        'east': 'Foyer',
        'south': 'Kitchen',
        'item': 'Haunted Spork',
        'text': 'You have entered the Dining Room'
    },
    'Billiards Room': {
        'name': 'Billiards Room',
        'west': 'Foyer',
        'item': 'Lucky Rabbit Foot',
        'text': 'You are in the Billiards Room'
    },
    'Kitchen': {
        'name': 'Kitchen',
        'north': 'Dining Room',
        'east': 'Great Hall',
        'south': 'Laundry',
        'item': 'Silver Spoon',
        'text': 'Welcome to the Kitchen'
    },
    'Great Hall': {
        'name': 'Great Hall',
        'north': 'Foyer',
        'west': 'Kitchen',
        'south': 'Master Suite',
        'east': 'Observatory',
        'item': 'Monkey Paw',
        'text': 'The Great Hall welcomes you'
    },
    'Observatory': {
        'name': 'Observatory',
        'west': 'Great Hall',
        'south': 'Armory',
        'item': 'Ancient Curse',
        'text': 'You have entered the Observatory',
    },
    # Boss Room
    'Laundry': {
        'name': 'Laundry',
        'north': 'Kitchen',
        'east': 'Master Suite',
        'item': 'Lucky Hat',
        'text': 'You have entered the Laundry'
    },
    'Master Suite': {
        'name': 'Master Suite',
        'north': 'Great Hall',
        'west': 'Laundry',
        'south': 'Greenhouse',
        'east': 'Armory',
        'item': 'Horseshoe Belt Buckle',
        'text': 'This is the Master Suite'
    },
    'Armory': {
        'name': 'Armory',
        'west': 'Master Suite',
        'north': 'Observatory',
        'item': 'Shooting Star',
        'text': 'Welcome to the Armory'
    },
    'Greenhouse': {
        'name': 'Greenhouse',
        'north': 'Master Suite',
        'item': 'Four-Leaf Clover',
        'text': 'Welcome to the Greenhouse'
    },
}

# The following sets the player's initial location and items.
current_room = rooms['Foyer']
current_items = None

player_action = ''

show_instructions()

while True:
    player_status()
    player_action = input("What do you want to do?\n")
    player_action = player_action.split()

    if player_action[0] == 'exit':
        print("Come Back Soon")
        break

    elif len(player_action) != 2:
        print("That doesn't make any sense\n")

    elif player_action[0] == 'go':
        if player_action[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][player_action[1]]
        else:
            print("You cannot go that way")

    elif player_action[0] == 'get':
        if player_action[1] in rooms[current_room]:
            current_items += [player_action[1]]
            print("You got: ", player_action[1])
            del rooms[current_room]['item']
        else:
            print("What exactly were you looking for?")
```

I am taking the user input, breaking it into a list, using the first item as a command `player_action[0]` (lines 124 and 130) and attempting to use the second item `player_action[1]` as a target.

However, when I try to use the commands in the program, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\josep\OneDrive\Desktop\IT 140\ADVENTURE GAME\main.py", line 125, in 
> if player_action[1] in rooms[current_room]:
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

`if player_action[1] in rooms[current_room['name']]`

`current_room` is a dictionary... you cannot use a dictionary as a key to another dictionary (and you indeed are not when you create it...)

one of the keys of `current_room` is `"name"` that is actually the key into your rooms dictionary

change your other instance as well from

`current_room = rooms[current_room][player_action[1]]`

to

```
new_room_name = current_room[player_action[1]]
new_room = rooms[new_room_name]
current_room = new_room
```

Comment: This is the code for that block now:

    elif player_action[0] == 'go':
        if player_action[1] in rooms[current_room['name']]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][player_action[1]]
        else:
            print("You cannot go that way")

I am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You still have a `rooms[current_room]` instead of `rooms[current_room["name"]]`

Comment: I missed that. The "go" function works now.

I am now running into problems with the "get" command.

Comment: `rooms[current_room]` is a problem... everywhere you need to get the room_name and access it as `rooms[room_name]`